# How to extract variables from the best auto_arima model to fit it?

Tags: arima

I have a dataset with multiple cities and I'm trying to build an ARIMA model for each city, so in my code I'm splitting the data using a for loop and finding the best model before sending those parameters to the final fitting. My question is how can I automate the process? Is there any way to extract the p, d, q value out of the best model which is returned by the ARIMACheck function?

```
def ARIMACheck(data):
    from pmdarima import auto_arima  

    fit = auto_arima(data[20], trace=True)
    return fit

def ARIMA(data, p, d, q):    
    from statsmodels.tsa.arima.model import ARIMA
    
    x_train = data.iloc[:-200]
    x_test = data.iloc[-200:]
    y_test = x_test.loc[:, 20]
    model = ARIMA(x_train[20], order=(p,d,q))
    model = model.fit()
        
def Split(data):
    for i in range(7):
        data[i].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)
    
    for i in range(7):
        datatemp = data.copy()
        datatemp = datatemp.dropna(subset=[i])
        datamap = datatemp.copy()
        datamap = datamap.loc[:, 20]
        datamap.plot(figsize=(50,10))
        fit = ARIMACheck(datatemp)
        print(fit)
        ARIMA(datatemp, 1, 1, 2)

Split(data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `auto_arima` function returns an ARIMA object that runs on statsmodels, so you could just use the `fit` from you method `ARIMACheck(data)`.

If you want to create a new model with the statsmodels class, then you can use the following to extract the order from the `auto_arima` fit and use it to train a new model in your `ARIMA` method:

```
def ARIMA(data, fit):
    
    model = ARIMA(endog=x_train[20], order=fit.get_params().get("order")).fit()
```

and call the method by:
`ARIMA(datatemp, fit)`

`fit.get_params().get("order")` returns a tuple like (p, d, q) so you can access each element by `fit.get_params().get("order")[<index>]`.

Comment: This works, thank you so much!!
Just that I think the .fit() wouldn't be required as fit is already defined in the beginning, rest works perfect, thank you very much!